# Displaying the postfix/prefix expression as a parse tree using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, syntax, tree

I have successfully converted infix expression to postfix expression and was also able to evaluate the postfix expression but I am facing problem in generating a parse tree for the same with C/C++

My output :

```
           enter the expression string a+b*c
           the expression is correct
           the postfix expression is - abc *+
           enter the value of a-1
           enter the value of b-2
           enter the value of c-3
           the postfix expression is -abc*+
           result= 7
```

I also require to display: Syntax tree

```
               +          
             /   \                                
          *       a                               
         /   \                                               
        b     c
```

Any feedback would be very helpful in my project.

Thanks in Adv.

@LD: Thanks for your consistent help.  I need the pseudocode in turbo C. I don't know Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

It's much easier to "draw" them like the following:

```
+
  a
  *
    b
    c
```

Or, if you want to use simple character graphics (I've changed the `+` and `*` operators to `Add` and `Mul`, to avoid clashing with the graphics):

```
Add
+-- a
+-- Mul
    +-- b
    +-- c
```

The trick to doing this is possible draw a subtree in isolation (e.g. the `mul` tree), and then draw it with suitable prefixes when drawing the outer tree.

In fact, if you are familiar with C++ stream buffers, you could create a prefixing stream buffer that handles the prefixes and simply print the inner tree.

The big difference compared to the style you suggested is that your style simply doesn't scale. If, for example the top operator would have two *big* subtrees, they would have been drawn extremely far apart.

**EDIT:** A slightly more complex tree could be drawn like this:

```
Add
+---Sub
|    +---Div
|    |    +---p
|    |    +---q
|    +---y
+---Mul
     +---b
     +---c
```

**EDIT:** On request, here comes some pseudo-code (which, incidentally, is acceptable by a Ruby interpreter). You must, however, use a suitable C++ data structure to represent the tree.

```
# Return the drawn tree as an array of lines.
#
# node ::= string
# node ::= [string, node, node]
def render_tree(node, prefix0 = "", prefix = "")
  if (node.is_a?(String))
    puts prefix0 + node         # Value
  else
    puts prefix0 + node[0]      # Operator
    render_tree(node[1], prefix  + "+---", prefix + "|    ")
    render_tree(node[2], prefix  + "+---", prefix + "     ")
  end
end
render_tree(["Add", ["Sub", ["Div", "p", "q"], "y"], ["Mul", "b", "c"]])
```

Comment: @LD: Thanks.. it would be very helpful if you can provide us with a sample code of the above mentioned method

Comment: The "prefixing" streambuf is simply a special case of a filtering streambuf---there's very good support for this sort of thing in `boost::iostream`.  Basically, the filter would have a flag `isAtStartOfLine`, initialized to `true`, and set to `ch == '\n'` each time you output a character.  When called upon to output a character, if `isAtStartOfLine`, you output the prefix first.

Comment: @newars: In fact, this is a good exercise, so I suggest that you make a stab at this yourself. (To make it simple, forget what I said about prefixing streambuffers.) Hint: Write a function that takes a tree representation and two *prefixes*, one to be used for the first line of a subtree and one for the body. Call the functions recursively for the subtrees, with longer prefixes. If you feel that you can't figure it out, I will post some pseudo-code here for you.

Comment: And as much as I like the filtering streambuf solution (Dietmar Kühl and I are the inventors of it), it may be overkill in this case.  Just pass an additional `std::string indent` parameter to the `print` function, which defaults to an empty string, and is passed to the recursive requests using the expression `indent.empty() ? " +- " : " |  " + indent`.